# how to enumerate over key/value collection to set parameters/env-variables in kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

I have a collection of key/value pairs and would like to enumerate over it under `env:` section so that I dont have to hardcode key/value pairs. The list of key/value pairs is dynamically growing and hence this need. Is it possible to refer to a collection or enumerate over it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well... the structure of `Pod` definition `yaml` is strictly defined and you can't introduce any changes which do not conform to the specification. So this structure must be kept:

```
...
env:
- name: DEMO_GREETING
  value: "Hello from the environment"
- name: DEMO_FAREWELL
  value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
...
```

To the best of my knowledge, you can't do it in such a simple way by referring a file containing the list of `key:value` pairs. If you have your list of `key:value` pairs stored in a file, you can write a fairly simple bash script which iterates through it and updates your `yaml` accordingly e.g. by using `kubectl patch`.

Actually it's possible to use `envFrom` instead of env but it [requires](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#envfromsource-v1-core) using [`configMapRef`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables) or a [`secretRef`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-secret-as-container-environment-variables) so first you would need to create a `Secret` or a `ConfigMap` containing your `key:value` pairs.